# H2 server DB created through Spring not accessible

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource, h2

versions I use:

- Spring version: 4.0.5.RELEASE
- H2 version: 1.3.174
- Hibernate version: 4.3.6.Final

I used to have a working setup where I create an H2 server and a dataSource using my applicationContext when deploying a war file. My configuration is like this:

```
<bean id = "h2Server"
      class="org.h2.tools.Server"
      factory-method="createTcpServer"
      init-method="start"
      destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg value="-tcp,-tcpAllowOthers,-tcpPort,8045" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" depends-on="h2Server">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
```

Then I defined a

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
```

with the jpaProperty defined to let hibernate generate all the tables automatically:

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

This works like a charm and when my application is deployed all the tables are created automatically. This is great for a test setup, but for the production release we would like to turn off the automatic generation of tables by hibernate, and we want to manage the sql creation and migration scripts ourselves.

Therefore I decided to use flyway as a DB migration tool and I removed the following line from the EntityManager definition:

```
 <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

This seems to work and the database is created and has a minimal size, but when I try to connect to it using Squirrel, I get the following exception:

[image: squirrel screenshot]

I would expect that if the H2Server and datasource beans are created by Spring, the DB is accessible using it's driver, url, username, password.

My first idea was that they were not created because of lazy initialization, while the hibernate table creation implies the beans to be really initialized. I tried to set the property of lazy initialization to false for both properties, but no luck...

I must be missing something, but can't see it for now...
Is there a way to make the DB available for connections once the application is deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: everything was working fine. I put a breakpoint in the start and stop methods of the org.h2.tools.Server class and activated remote debugging when deploying the application to my tomcat server.

I noticed the server started, but some time later, I arrived also in the stop method. Deeper investigation showed me the following lines in the tomcat command:

```
04-Nov-2014 13:00:28.240 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core
    .StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
04-Nov-2014 13:00:55.961 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core
    .StandardContext.startInternal Context [/healthdata_hd4res] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Then in the localhost.log file, I found following error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "CONFIGURATIONS" not found; SQL statement:
    select configurat0_.CONFIGURATION_ID as CONFIGUR1_1_, configurat0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT2_1_, configurat0_.KEY as KEY3_1_, configurat0_.UPDATED_ON as UPDATED_4_1_, configurat0_.VALID_FROM as VALID_FR5_1_, configurat0_.VALID_TILL as VALID_TI6_1_, configurat0_.VALUE as VALUE7_1_ from CONFIGURATIONS configurat0_ where configurat0_.KEY=? and (configurat0_.VALID_FROM is null or configurat0_.VALID_FROM<=?) and (configurat0_.VALID_TILL is null or configurat0_.VALID_TILL>=?) [42102-174]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:172)
```

There were 2 classes that implemented a ServletContextListener to inject data into existing tables. Since the tables were not yet created, the error was generated and my h2Server was shutdown during deployment...

Comment: OK. That doesn't explain the exception you are seeing (posted in the question), but if it works now then I guess problem solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are using H2 version 1.4.181 on the client side. (The last part of the error code, 90067-181, is the build number of H2).

On the server side, you wrote you are using H2 version 1.3.174.

The problem is most likely an incompatibility between the H2 client and H2 server. In theory, it should not be a problem, but it looks like there is a bug in H2 which prevents those versions to work together.

I suggest to upgrade the server to 1.3.181 as well, and append `;mv_store=false` to the database URL to disable the new storage engine that is still in beta.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, but unfortunately no luck... I can't manage to connect to the DB immediately after deployment using Java code, so I think it's really unavailable and there is an error in my spring configuration...